# Plesk isn't serving up the right page

Tags: domain-name-system

I have Plesk configured to serve up subdomain.mydomain.com as well as mydomain.com.  But, instead of displaying the content, no matter which URL I go to, it displays the default Plesk page.  I've deleted all my DNS information and re-added, but can't get it to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does going to the actual URL of the page work e.g. mydomain.com/inde.html?

Plesk often adds a default.htm page that displays the plesk details to each site, you may need to remove this to get things to work as they should.